# Get $post object of next post

Tags: wordpress, object, post

Is there a way to get `$post` object of the Next or Previous post in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
//get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat,$excluded_categories,$previous)
$nextPost = get_adjacent_post(false, '', false);
$previousPost = get_adjacent_post(false, '', true);
?>
```

More information here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post

Comment: What's the standard on this: do I put the Previous post link on the left and Next post link on the right, Or is it the other way around?

Comment: It's entirely up to you, but I would do previous on the left and next on the right.

Comment: Food for thought: Instead of saying "<<Previous Post" or "Next Post>>" you could use their titles instead since you now have access to the post object. But ultimately, it's your baby, so do what you feel is best and makes the most sense.

Comment: maiorano84, I thought so too but suddenly it just didn't feel right when I did it. So I flipped it and behold—it didn't feel right either. Haha, I'm doomed!